# plot the media of grouped data by two variables in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

frame that looks like this

```
df<- data.frame(samples=1:60, location=rep(letters[1:3], 20), 
                variable=c(rep("A", 20), rep("B", 20), rep("C", 20)), value=rnorm(60))

df
  samples location variable       value
1       1        a        A  0.32513726
2       2        b        A  2.05029602
3       3        c        A -0.10470011
4       4        a        A  0.17142511
5       5        b        A  0.94286900
6       6        c        A -0.01325556
```

What I need is to plot (a dot plot) the `location` (a,b, or c) (x-axis) and the median `value`(y-axis) for each location in each of the different `variable` (A, B or C).

I would like to do it in `ggplot2`

So far I have using

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(Location, value), group="variable") + stat_summary(fun.y="median", geom="point")
```

But it doesn't work..

Comment: Best to use `set.seed` for reproducibility in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `group` variable inside `aes`, also you probably want to specify it as `color` at the same time so that you can see better, in order to draw lines between dots within the same group, you can add another `stat_summary` and specify the `geom` as `line`:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(location, value, col = variable, group = variable)) + 
       stat_summary(fun.y = "median", geom = "point") + 
       stat_summary(fun.y = "median", geom = "line")
```

[image]

Comment: Is this correct? I get `median(df[df$variable == "A" & df$location == 'b',]$value)`  to be `[1] -0.9222727`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Psidom, is there an easy way to draw a line between the dots?

Comment: Ok, there is no set seed state.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to get this data is to use dplyr. The benefit of this is you can plot it using ggplot2 without knowing many of the stat_summary transforms.

Edited: To include a `geom_line()` layer grouped by `variable`.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df%>%group_by(variable, location) %>%
  summarise(median = median(value)) 
ggplot(df2, aes(location, median, col=variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = variable))
```

[image: Median grouped geom_line]